# Flask doesn't match route

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a route linked to a Flask-RESTful Resource:

```
api.add_resource(File, '/api/files/<int:id>')
```

If I now want to access that route via

```
/api/files/89?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc0FkbWluIjp0cnVlLCJ1c2VySWQiOjEsImV4cCI6MTQ3OTg0MTcxN30.DkoPeMeXms9j0nzmEAsGKOpIi_cRyTf4m6mQJjl17o0
```

i get:

```
"The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. You have requested this URI [/api/files/89] but did you mean /api/files/<int:id> or /api/files or /api/users/<int:id> ?"
```

If I try to simply:

```
/api/files/89
```

without the query parameter, everything works fine.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Looks like your key is not url-encoded. I believe those `.` characters need to be encoded properly.

Comment: @sytech You can try it directly in the browser dev tools: `'.' === encodeURIComponent('.')` gives `true`. So, `.` is not required to be somehow encoded.

Comment: @Lelsoos, could you provide us other routes mentioned in the error message?

Comment: @IvanVelichko do you want the implementation of this routes or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Lelsoos, just definitions like this one `api.add_resource(File, '/api/files/<int:id>')`.

Comment: Actually replacing the dots in the string fixed the problem..

Comment: @IvanVelichko you're right. The query string is probably fine as is by RFC standards. But I think it might be confusing flask-restful. Otherwise, the problem might be that flask-restful wants that to be defined explicitly; maybe something like `parser.add_argument('key', location='args')`

Comment: Im using the native request from flask, not the parser from RESTful

Comment: So percent-encoding the `.` in the string worked? I wonder if you'd be able to use the string as it was if you defined the route with a trailing slash, then made the request to `/api.files/89/?key=whatever`

Comment: Now its not working again. I really dont know why. I replaced all . with + and then it worked, at least for some mins. Now Im getting the same error again.

Comment: @sytech Adding a trial slash to the route doesnt change it for me. The other routes are:
api.add_resource(FileList, '/api/files'), api.add_resource(Users, '/api/users/<int:id>')

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error? Is it the same result with debugging enabled/disabled? I'm not sure `+` is the way to encode it, I don't think. In the query string I believe `+` is a substitute for a space character. But beside the point for now, I suppose.

Comment: I switched to production mode, then I get the same error

Comment: // Edit; Yep, the problem below solved it for me. Thank you everyone!

I eventually found the error. Im basically so stupid. Today I did some refactoring and moved some config files around. The return of the mentioned route should be a file download. The upload folder is defined in one of the config files. And due to some os.path stuff, the folder path got corrupted. I am currently fixing this. I think this is the mistake..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It wasnt something related to the router, instead I messed up the view logic.